# How to get .x and .y from random movie clip?

Tags: actionscript-3, random, actionscript, movieclip

For example, i have **"b1"-"b24"** mc instances in scene, and "**cross**" movie clip.
So, I want to achieve something like this:

```
cross.x="b"+Math.ceil(1+Math.random()*23).x;
cross.y="b"+Math.ceil(1+Math.random()*23).y;
```

It is wrong, because it is "Number", if I try

```
aaa="b"+Math.ceil(1+Math.random()*23);
cross.x=Object(aaa).x;
```

It also fails,

> Property x not found on String and there is no default value.

BTW. **round**, instead of **ceil**:

> Math.round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write like this

```
cross.x = this["b" + Math.ceil(1 + Math.random() * 23)].x;
cross.y = this["b" + Math.ceil(1 + Math.random() * 23)].y;
```

Comment: i will, in 1 minute %)

Comment: But it also prompts some strange lag, "A term is undefined and has no properties"? what is this?

Comment: can you tell me case?

Comment: I do not get it, obviously if element is missing it cause this error, and also it had prompt i dont know why on elements. Just deleted them and placed another time, and it works perfectly. Just wierd bug i guess.